# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3307' (111)")

Tags: docker, rest, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

I've setup my project Django REST API on GCP VM running Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS in a virtual environment. I'm currently configuring the following open source Rest API project :
https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api

The Okuna CLI uses docker-compose to spawn and coordinate the following docker services.
webserver - A server running the Okuna API
db - A server with a MariaDB database
redis - A server with a Redis database
scheduler - A server responsible for running the scheduled Okuna jobs such as curating Explore/Top posts.
worker - A server responsible for processing the Okuna jobs such as publishing a post or curating posts

The Django backend opens up successfully at the GCP external IP address as configured by me in the okuna-cli.py. However I face problems when I run

> python3.8 manage.py migrate

The Error trace

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3307' (111)")

The .env file(https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api/blob/master/templates/.env) has the following pertaining to the above error :

```
# [NAME] ALLOWED_HOSTS
# [DESCRIPTION] Django variable specifying allowed hosts.
# [REQUIRED][PRODUCTION]
# [MORE] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
# ALLOWED_HOSTS=openbook.social

# [GROUP] SQL Database Configuration
# [DESCRIPTION] The SQL database configuration
# [REQUIRED][ALWAYS]
RDS_DB_NAME=okuna
RDS_USERNAME=root
RDS_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
RDS_PORT=3307
RDS_HOSTNAME_READER=127.0.0.1
RDS_HOSTNAME_WRITER=127.0.0.1
# [NAME] RDS_PASSWORD
# [DESCRIPTION] The password for the SQL Database.
RDS_PASSWORD={{SQL_PASSWORD}}

# [GROUP] Redis Database configuration Configuration
# [DESCRIPTION] The redis database configuration
# [REQUIRED][ALWAYS]
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6380
# [NAME] REDIS_PASSSWORD
# [DESCRIPTION] The password for the REDIS Database. If using okuna-cli, obtained from .okuna-cli.json
REDIS_PASSWORD={{REDIS_PASSWORD}}
```

The .docker-compose.env file(https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api/blob/master/templates/.docker-compose.env) has the following pertaining to the above error :

```
# [NAME] ALLOWED_HOSTS
# [DESCRIPTION] Django variable specifying allowed hosts.
# [REQUIRED][PRODUCTION]
# [MORE] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
# ALLOWED_HOSTS=openbook.social

# [GROUP] SQL Database Configuration
# [DESCRIPTION] The SQL database configuration
# [REQUIRED][ALWAYS]
RDS_DB_NAME=okuna
RDS_USERNAME=root
RDS_HOSTNAME=db.okuna
RDS_PORT=3306
RDS_HOSTNAME_READER=db.okuna
RDS_HOSTNAME_WRITER=db.okuna
# [NAME] RDS_PASSWORD
# [DESCRIPTION] The password for the SQL Database. If using okuna-cli, obtained from .okuna-cli.json
RDS_PASSWORD={{SQL_PASSWORD}}

# [GROUP] Redis Database configuration Configuration
# [DESCRIPTION] The redis database configuration
# [REQUIRED][ALWAYS]
REDIS_HOST=redis.okuna
REDIS_PORT=6379
# [NAME] REDIS_PASSSWORD
# [DESCRIPTION] The password for the REDIS Database.
REDIS_PASSWORD={{REDIS_PASSWORD}}
```

The settings.py file(https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api/blob/master/openbook/settings.py) has the following pertaining to the above error :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')
if IS_PRODUCTION:
    if not ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        raise NameError('ALLOWED_HOSTS environment variable is required when running on a production environment')
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [allowed_host.strip() for allowed_host in ALLOWED_HOSTS.split(',')]
else:
    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        logger.info('ALLOWED_HOSTS environment variable ignored.')
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']   
    
REDIS_HOST = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
REDIS_PORT = int(os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT', '6379'))
REDIS_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD')
```

Here is the docker-compose-full.yaml(https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api/blob/master/docker-compose-full.yml)

```html
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    container_name: okuna-api
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./.docker/api
    privileged: true
    extra_hosts:
      - db.okuna:172.16.16.4
      - redis.okuna:172.16.16.5
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/okuna-api
      - ./.docker-cache/pip:/root/.cache/pip
    ports:
      - 80:80
    working_dir: /opt/okuna-api
    networks:
      okuna:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.16.1
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .docker-compose.env
  worker:
    container_name: okuna-worker
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./.docker/worker
    privileged: true
    extra_hosts:
      - db.okuna:172.16.16.4
      - redis.okuna:172.16.16.5
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/okuna-api
      - ./.docker-cache/pip:/root/.cache/pip
    working_dir: /opt/okuna-api
    networks:
      okuna:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.16.2
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    env_file:
      - .docker-compose.env
  scheduler:
    container_name: okuna-scheduler
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./.docker/scheduler
    privileged: true
    extra_hosts:
      - db.okuna:172.16.16.4
      - redis.okuna:172.16.16.5
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/okuna-api
      - ./.docker-cache/pip:/root/.cache/pip
    working_dir: /opt/okuna-api
    networks:
      okuna:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.16.3
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    env_file:
      - .docker-compose.env
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.5
    hostname: db.okuna
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306
    privileged: false
    networks:
      okuna:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.16.4
    command: --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    env_file:
      - .docker-compose.env
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    privileged: false
    ports:
      - 6379
    networks:
      okuna:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.16.5
    env_file:
      - .docker-compose.env
    volumes:
      - redisdb:/bitnami/redis/data

volumes:
  mariadb:
  redisdb:

networks:
  okuna:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.16.16.0/16"
```

Need help here. Thanks.

Comment: Please include your `docker-compose.yaml` file. It's hard to be sure without seeing it, but if your database and application are running in separate containers than `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) is the wrong hostname to use for the database. You should be using the name of the database container.

Comment: @larsks Have added the docker-compose-full.yaml to the details. Kindly check.

Comment: @larsks. Could you help ? On ypur request, I uploaded the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows :
The ip4 address of the databases mentioned in the containers to be created in the yaml file needs to be added to the .env file inplace of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker ps -a` to identify the port that you are binding to 3306 if you're trying to acces it from your localhost, if you're trying to acces it from another container inside your network (okuna) consider using the service name, if you refer to it as 127.0.0.1 from inside your container it will try to connect to the api container itself

Comment: The mange.py is from okuna-api container which is trying to access another container which contains the maria db database and redis database and 2 other containers which contain the worker and scheduler. Where exactly and what changes do I have to make? An example would be helpful with regards to the docker-compose-full.yaml , docker-compose.env and the .env file above ? - Thanking in advance since I'm a newbie here.